# plotting data at the end of each iterate

Tags: python, matplotlib, non-linear-regression

I'm working with a dataframe including two columns and 40 rows (X, y). I have fitted different degrees of curves to this data in a loop. To visualize this process, I need to plot data and the fitted curve line, at the end of each iteration. I couldn't handle it. Would you please help me with it?
p.s. the code is as below:

```
error_list=[]
bias_list=[]
variance_list=[]
degrees=[1,3,7,11,16,20]
    
for degree in degrees:
    polybig_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree, include_bias=False)
    lin_regressor = LinearRegression()
    polynomial_regression  = Pipeline([("poly_features", polybig_features),("lin_regressor", lin_regressor)])
    
    polynomial_regression.fit(X, y)
     
    y_predict= polynomial_regression.predict(X)
    
    error = mean_squared_error(y, y_predict)
    
    error_list.append(error)
    
    bias_list.append(abs(((mean_squared_error(y, y_predict))-(np.var(y_predict)))))
    
    variance_list.append(np.var(y_predict))
    
    plt.plot(X, y_predict)
```

The result is not what I want. I want each fitted curve line to be shown in a unique plot.

Comment: Follow here: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.01-simple-line-plots.html

Comment: Where are you running this?